# "Save Image" doesn't work

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, browser, downloading, images, troubleshooting

Using Android 4.0.4 on the LG Optiomus P970 I cannot save images from browsers.

When using the preinstalled browser (not Chrome on this device) tap-and-hold brings up a context menu including "save image". Pressing that option closes the menu but otherwise has no effect.

When using Chrome choosing "save image" brings up a list of apps to use including Gallery, Dropbox and Google Drive (all three allow selecting an existing file only, but doing so doesn't change that file) and a couple of non-senical options like Camera, Camcorder, Audio and voice memo.

Any idea what might be going wrong or how I can troubleshoot it?

Comment: Are you sure it has no effect in the default browser? Once you've pressed **Save image**, it's done, so you shouldn't expect to see anything further. Go into the **Gallery** and look in the **Downloads** album.

Comment: Sadly no. Nothing there.